# How to find the lowest number of a grouped dataframe in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a table and I want to find the lowest number associated with each 'leadId' in my table. Here is a snapshot of it below:

| Index | leadId | repId | hoursSinceContacted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 261 | 1111 | 10391 |
| 2 | 261 | 2222 | 10247 |
| 3 | 261 | 3333 | 1149 |
| 4 | 261 | 4444 | 10247 |
| 5 | 262 | 5555 | 551 |
| 6 | 262 | 6666 | 982 |
| 6 | 262 | 3333 | 214 |

Is there a groupby statement I can use to get a table that looks like this?:

| Index | leadId | repId | hoursSinceContacted |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 261 | 3333 | 1149 |
| 6 | 262 | 3333 | 214 |

Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself that you are willing to share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Groupby` and then `min`

```
>>> df.groupby('leadId').min()
        Index  repId  hoursSinceContacted
leadId                                   
261         1   1111                 1149
262         5   3333                  214
```

Updated per @ALoliz comment, if you want the rows corresponding to the `min(hoursSinceContacted)`

```
df.loc[df.groupby('leadId')['hoursSinceContacted'].idxmin()]

   Index  leadId  repId  hoursSinceContacted
2      3     261   3333                 1149
6      6     262   3333                  214
```

Comment: I. Cannot. Believe. That. Fixed it. Thank you. I have been trying VERY complicated group bys and NOTHING was working.... except the simplest solution. Thank you again

Comment: Yes that happens to all of us. With pandas there is almost always a simple one line solution, `+1`. Your welcome

Comment: @KaelanMcGurk I don't think this is correct This separately considers the `min` for each field so they can come from different rows. (See how index is 5 in the output, not 6). Based on your output it seems like you want the entire row, based on the minimum of `hoursSinceContacted` for each leadId

Comment: @ALollz I see your point. As I am looking through my new dataframe and cross referencing it with multiple tables from my database, the dataframe appears correct. I am not sure why I am not getting the error you are stating, but at this point I do not want to question it.

Comment: I updated the post to account for that logic as well

Comment: Thank you. I tested the update and it is more correct than the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

df.groupby('leadid').agg({'hoursSinceContacted' : 'min'}).reset_index()

Answer (score 1):

try using as_index=False

```
df.groupby(['leadid'],as_index=False).agg({'hoursSinceContacted':['min','max']})


or

fp = df.pivot_table( columns='leadId', values='hoursSinceContacted', aggfunc={'min'})
print(fp)
```

output:

```
leadId   261  262
min     1149  214
```